# python equality precedence

Tags: python, equality, python-2.x

```
class L(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print 'invoked L.__eq__'
        return False

class R(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print 'invoked R.__eq__'
        return False

left = L()
right = R()
```

With this code, left side gets the first shot at comparison, as [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__eq__#object.__eq__) in the data model:

```
>>> left == right
invoked L.__eq__
False
```

But if we make a slight modification on line 6 (everything else the same):

```
class R(L):
```

Now the *right* side gets to have the first shot at comparison.

```
>>> left == right
invoked R.__eq__
False
```

Why is that?  Where is it documented, and what's the reason for the design decision?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is documented under the [numeric operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types), further down the page, with an explanation for why it works that way:

> Note: If the right operand’s type is a subclass of the left operand’s type and that subclass provides the reflected method for the operation, this method will be called before the left operand’s non-reflected method. This behavior allows subclasses to override their ancestors’ operations.

The [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) additionally mentions it in the section you were looking at:

> If the operands are of different types, and right operand’s type is a direct or indirect subclass of the left operand’s type, the reflected method of the right operand has priority, otherwise the left operand’s method has priority. Virtual subclassing is not considered.